# How do I install PDFBox on mac?

Tags: java, pdf, classpath

I'm new at this area and I would like to get help from you guys. The problem is that I have no idea how to start or where. I'm trying to install PDFBox on a mac computer for this project I'm doing.
So the question is: Where do I start and where can I find some good examples of using PDFBox.

I have read a lot on google but still im sitting here with nothing, I dont understand how I'm suppose to add the jar-files in CLASSPATH (pdfbox-1.8.2.jar,fontbox-1.8.2.jar,jempbox-1.8.2.jar etc..)

I would be grateful if someone could show me how to install this or these library(ies) and an example to read in a PDF file with JAVA-programming. Is this to much to ask? I have never asked anything on SOF.

Can somebody please help me, the deadline is getting closer :(

P.S. It's not a school project

Comment: I fear installing software (even if it is programming related) may be offtopic for SO. It may be on topic for other stack exchange sites. (I also don't know, i'm not just being petty)

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question read this SO question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842063/where-to-install-jar-files-on-os-x-so-other-java-applications-will-find-them

It's normal to supply the jar file with your application and provide some method of setting the class path.  e.g. by wrapping the java command in a shell script.

Alternatively, Oracle have provided [instructions for making a standalone app bundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html).

The second part is more tricky.  PDFBox is quite complex, but they supply some examples in the  [PDFBox cookbook](http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html)

Comment: A BIG thank you @JeremyP! I really appreciate your answer, it helped :)